# Allow multiple votes for the same option in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to make a Google Form where users are allowed (or required) to cast two votes, and they are allowed to vote twice for the same option. Is that possible? I haven't been able to figure it out myself.

That scheme (multiple votes allowed for same option) is very popular in my country (probably all countries) for polls for choosing a name, a theme etc. Especially if there are few voters.

Comment: You mean simply tell people to vote twice, calling them selves Name1 and Name2? Could be done, but it seems error prone. I could also add all options twice so people could select it twice to give it two votes. Both seem unprofessional however...

Comment: Instead of using a multiple choice question with several options, use a question for each option and ask the respondents to write the number of votes that they giving to each option.